# encountering Notice Undefined Index

Tags: php, ajax, function

I already created this script to insert in my DB but always having problem Notice: Undefined index: please let me know why i'm having this error.

Thank you

```
<?php
 ob_start();
  include("db.php");
  if(isset($_POST['send'])!="")
  {
   $Service_Number=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Service_Number']);
       $rundate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rundate']);
       $Bytes_In=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Bytes_In']);
       $Bytes_Out=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Bytes_Out']);
       $Average_Mbps_Upload=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Average_Mbps_Upload']);
       $Average_Mbps_Download=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Average_Mbps_Download']);
       $Average_Excess_Mbps=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Average_Excess_Mbps']);
       $update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO form_element_copy(Service_Number,rundate,Bytes_In,Bytes_Out,Average_Mbps_Upload,Average_Mbps_Download,Average_Excess_Mbps)VALUES
                                      ('$Service_Number','$rundate','$Bytes_In','$Bytes_Out','$Average_Mbps_Upload','$Average_Mbps_Download','$Average_Excess_Mbps')");

  if($update)
  {
      $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";

  }
  else
  {
     $errormsg="Something went wrong, Try again";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg');</script>";
  }
  }
 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: You'll need to add a link or form element that calls/submits to a php page. In that php page, sanitize the values, write your insert sql query, and bind the values to the query (paramaterized query).

Comment: thank you for that, but can you give me specific example , I'm sorry for asking as i said i'm just newly in functions and been trying to play with the code but still not working.

Comment: Hi i just made this script but its look like im have problem again

Comment: isset returns a boolean (true or false), remove the !="" in your if, just leave the isset

Comment: Hi Already did that but still the same -  phobia82